# Request API data into Express view

Tags: node.js, express, ejs

Newbie here. I'm trying to send data I received from making making an API call (when the user requests the zoopla page) into an `index.ejs` view. I'm trying to pass the `graph_url` by passing it in the `res.render`.

The `graph_url` logs correctly, so the API call is coming back, however I get the following error in my terminal:

```
ReferenceError: graph_url is not defined
```

Here is my `index.js` request for the page:

```
app.get('/zoopla', function(req, res){
  request(zoopla, function(err, res, data){
    var data = JSON.parse(data);
    var graph_url = data.area_values_url
    console.log(graph_url);
  });
  res.render('index', { title : "zoopla", graph : graph_url});
});
```

Comment: Javascript is asynchronous. You need to put your render function inside your request callback.

Answer (score 0):

`graph_url` is not defined because is out of the local scope, and also you are trying to render the page **before** the previous *async* `request()` call complete.

try with:

```
app.get('/zoopla', function(req, res){
  request(zoopla, function(err, res, data){
    if (err) {
       /* handle errors */
    }

    var data = JSON.parse(data);
    var graph_url = data.area_values_url
    console.log(graph_url);
    res.render('index', { title : "zoopla", graph : graph_url});
  });
});
```